# plug in for android studio to connect to TFS on mac

Tags: macos, tfs, android-studio

is there any plug-in for android studio to connect to TFS?
i've already used Git-Tf from microsoft but i want to know if there is any other solutions out there , i've already searched Google but it all the results is about Git-Tf

Answer (score 1):

From  Android Studio menu, select Preferences-> Plugins -> then browse TFS or azure DevOps and install.

You can use from vcs menu or file ->New-Project From Version Control->and select login and browse repo and clone

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In TFS 2013 you have the native Git. Then you can have the original command line Git, commiting on TFS, through any tool.

Comment: Samer, on 2012 version you can use Git by this way... But the repository on server is not Git. I recommend you migrate the TFS. Is better!